# Setting icons in Unity3d standalone player

Tags: build, icons, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use Unity, with a build script that creates my application by ultimately invoking BuildPipeline from the script. I am trying to figure out how to set up the icons, however.  After calling PlayerSettings.SetIconsForTargetGroup and invoking BuildPipline.BuildPlayer, the appropriate icon does not show up for the executable file produced, nor display when the program is running.

I am currently using the following code.

```
Texture2D texture = AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath(iconFile) as Texture2D;               
int [] sizeList = PlayerSettings.GetIconSizesForTargetGroup(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone);
Texture2D[] iconList = new Texture2D[sizeList.Length];
for(int i=0;i<sizeList.Length;i++)
{
    int iconSize = sizeList[i];
    iconList[i] = (Texture2D)Instantiate(texture);
    iconList[i].Resize(iconSize,iconSize,TextureFormat.ARGB32,false);
}
PlayerSettings.SetIconsForTargetGroup(BuildTargetGroup.Standalone,iconList);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.   Thank you

Comment: Having the same problem, ever figure it out?

Comment: nope.... I'm not even doing any unity programming anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Using `BuildTargetGroup.Unknown` works for me.

Comment: Try this:

Texture2D[] icons = new Texture2D[1];
icons[0] = AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath("Assets/Resources/Icon.png") as Texture2D;  
PlayerSettings.SetIconsForTargetGroup(BuildTargetGroup.Unknown, icons);

Comment: No that doesn't work for me, how have you set up Icon.png in Unity? Also, I am building on Windows for Windows Standalone.

Comment: For the above I was also building for Windows. Icon.png should be as GUI.

Comment: Double check that it has the filename extension in the path - a missing ".png" threw no errors for me, but made the icons not appear. Mine are imported as "Advanced" and I had no problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me:

```
BuildTargetGroup.Unknown
```

But with an unwanted outcome: Unity does not override all icon sizes when setting one single Texture2D PNG, so Windows Explorer swaps the icon of my application EXE between the Unity default icon and my icon for different resolutions. Definitely, seems like a bug in Unity3D BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(..) or SetIconsForTargetGroup(..).

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling BuildPipline.BuildPlayer for OSX, then you need to specify full folder:

> /MyPath/MyApp.app

i.e. don't leave out the ".app" part, because without that Unity builds the app, but doesn't include icons or splash image in resolution dialog.